# Lightbox 2 will not display image

Tags: lightbox2

I have tried to implement the latest version of Lightbox as of 30 June 2015.  I have loaded the js files (jquery.min.js and lightbox.js in that order).  I also have added the css line to my head section as well.  I have even tried loading lightbox.min.js

I have added the data-lightbox attribute to the image ink.  When I click on the link to show the image, all that happens is I go to the image itself.  It is like I opened the image from my local machine in a browser.  No lightbox effect or features at all.

The page in question can be seen at http://www.kilajager.com/new/bs.php

The 5 images side by side at the top are my links to the full image.

Below are snippets of the code:

```
<head>
<title>Kila Jager Modeling Portfolio | Portfolio</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
</head>
```

```
<a href="images/bs02.jpg" class="b-link-stripe b-animate-go  thickbox play-icon" data-lightbox="bonnie" data-title="Image 02">
  <img src="images/bsslid2.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple instructions in [Lightbox 2 website](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) are <strike>currently inadequate</strike> *(as of now, they have been [updated](https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/463) to be adequate)*.

Lightbox 2 will not work with versions of jQuery below 1.7. And the placement of the `<script>` tag matters.

1. Use **jQuery 1.7 or above**.

   - If you don't already use jQuery in your page, simply use `lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js` instead as it includes jQuery 2.1.4.
   - If you already use it, upgrade to jQuery 1.7 or above and test out your existing jQuery-based code and plugins. *Hopefully nothing else breaks* `=)`
2. Put the Lightbox 2 `<script>` tag (for the JavaScript file) **at the end of the page**, just before the body closing tag (`</body>`).

   - The `<link>` tag for the CSS can remain in the `<head>` tag.

Comment: The instructions now note the placement of the script tag and note the min requirement of jQuery 1.7. http://localhost:8000/dist/#getting-started